# C++ qsort inside function on array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, function, qsort

Me again, I'm working on the qsort of the array of `zipType`'s. The compare function I wrote looks like this:

```
    int compare(const void *v1, const void *v2){
        const struct zipType *p1 = v1;
        const struct zipType *p2 = v2;
        if (p1->postalCode > p2->postalCode)
            return(+1);
        else if (p1->postalCode < p2->postalCode)
            return(-1);
        else
            return(0);
        }
```

This is the function that uses it:

```
   void binRead(zipType *zip, fstream *input){
   int junk;
   int count;
   int end;
   input->seekg(0,ios::end);
   end=input->tellg();
   count=input->tellg()/24;
   input->seekg(0);

   while(input->tellg()!=end){  
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        input->read((char*)( &(zip[i].postalCode) ), sizeof(int    ));
        input->read((char*)( &junk ),                sizeof(int    ));
        input->read((char*)( &(zip[i].longitude)  ), sizeof(double  ));
        input->read((char*)( &(zip[i].latitude)   ), sizeof(double  ));
        cout << "Currently at position" << input->tellg() << endl;
     }
   }

   cout << "Array Created, Please wait while I sort" << endl;
   qsort(zip, count, sizeof(int), compare);
   usleep(3000000);
   cout << "Array Sorted" << endl;

  }
```

The error I'm getting is a couple of these:

```
    invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘const zipType*’ [-fpermissive]
    const struct zipType *p2 = v2;
```

And one of these:

```
     error: cannot convert ‘zipType’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void qsort(void*, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void*, const void*))’
     qsort(*zip, count, sizeof(int), compare);
```

Any ideas what I should be doing?

Comment: C or C++? There can only be one.

Comment: you need to call `qsort()` like this. `qsort((void *)zip, count, sizeof(*zip), compare);`  since zip is a class w/multiple elements the third argument to `qsort()` is the size of each element that `qsort()` is sorting.  Also the first value to `qsort()` needs to be the base pointer to an array of elements each of the size of passed as the third parameter.

Comment: `const struct zipType *p2 = (const struct zipType*)v2;`

Comment: @user2990286: Why is it that you don't want to use std::sort?

Comment: Its just part of the assignment to use qsort instead of sort. No real reason other than that. I could do this in main much easier but I thought it would look better if the function went ahead and sorted. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) firstly.Then you will know the meaning of each parameter.

Your qsort should be like :
`qsort((void*)zip, count, sizeof(struct zipType), compare);`

The third parameter `size` means the size of the elem in the array, should be `zipType` not `int`.

Comment: the whole item is zipType but I'm sorting based on the postalCode, which is of size int. So I thought I needed to put int there. I have read qsort, for the past hour. and its simple, until I put it inside a function and sort structs with it and have to start referring to memory instead of a variable.

Comment: `qsort` doesn't care that you're comparing by postal codes. It needs to know the size of the item so that it can correctly compute the addresses of the first item, the second item, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the first error, you need to cast from `void*` inside the comparison routine:

```
auto p1 = static_cast<const struct zipType*>(v1);
```

To fix the second error, I think we again need to cast, but this time to `void*`:

```
qsort(static_cast<void*>(zip), count, sizeof(zipType*), compare)
```

Honestly, I'm not sure why this cast is needed. If I'm remembering my conversion rules correctly, `zipType*` should be convertible to `void*` implicitly. If anyone knows, post a comment and I'll edit the answer or, if you can, just edit the answer.

Note that you want the size of the the elements in the array for the [third parameter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), not `sizeof(int)` here. You have an array of `zipType*` not `int`.

Since you are using C++ (deduced because you are using `std::cout`), though, try [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/). It is more type-safe and can often be optimized better.

```
std::sort(zip, std::advance(zip, count), compare)
```

Also, since this is C++, you don't need to say `struct zipType`. You can just say `zipType`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I would use sort, but for this assignment they want qsort. It would have been easy to do in main but I get really confused when I start using *variable and &variable.